# event or Action<> on method complete?

Tags: wpf, events, asynchronous, delegates, prism

Presuming you have an email folder and messages in it. Each message has Body property, which needs to be loaded async and notify you when done, how would you approach this?

1 - Message.LoadBody() + event Message.BodyLoadComplete

2 - Message.LoadBody(Action completeDelegate)

For the sake of completeness WPF and Prism are involved.

Thanks!

Edit:

Message will be a UI entity which will wrap a IMessage interface (that is not UI Ready (no INPC)), so the reason i'm asking is that we have to settle for an interface between UI and business layer.. IMessage. (The Business layer will be using an Imap library that already has some async pattern, but we don't want to depend too much on any imp, thats why i'm trying to figure out the best interface ..

Comment: A more descriptive and open title might be "Best pattern for asynchronous methods?"

Comment: i m not debating aync patterns, plus on a thread like that it always ends up with "depends what you are doing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, I'd use:

```
Task<string> LoadBodyAsync()
```

(You might want to implement this using [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx).)

The caller can then add continuations etc however they wish... and most importantly, in the brave new world of .NET 4.5 and C# 5, this will work seamlessly with the `async`/`await` features.

Comment: Inside Load body another imap library is called that performs the loading on another thread so using Task was my first idea too, but in this case is not really an option..

Comment: @Zapacila: Why not? Saying "it's not an option" doesn't exactly give much information.

Comment: @Joe there would be 2 threads one created by the Task and 1 by the inap library..

Comment: @Zapacila: Not necessarily. I wasn't suggesting using `Task.Factory.StartNew` - I suggested using `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`. You can set the result on the task completion source when the IMAP operation completes.

Comment: @Joe Awesoome solution, my bad for jumping ahead. I read more on TaskCompletionSource on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/02/9685804.aspx and its a match. Now the IMessage interface may have other events on data change, should we mix this 2 different paradigms ?

Comment: @Zapacila: I'm not sure I follow, but I'd *try* not to mix the two paradigms if possible.

Comment: @Zapacila: "Joe"? You must be new here. ;) Follow [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) for more information.

Comment: :))) not new, just young an impatient. sorry for messing up your name

Answer (score 1):

Of your two options:

```
Message.LoadBody() // Plus an event, Message.BodyLoadComplete

// or ...

Message.LoadBody(Action completeDelegate)
```

The event option is more flexible and may sometimes be less painful to use.  If you don't care when or if `LoadBody` completes, then you aren't forced to provide a fake callback.  And you can bind the completion event to multiple event handlers, which might sometimes be useful (e.g. if multiple UI controls need to be updated).

Both your solutions are non-typical, though.  The typical "old" way to do this is for `LoadBody` to be split into `BeginLoadBody` and `EndLoadBody`, and give the user an `IAsyncResult`.  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx).  The typical "new" way to do it is outlined in Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Prism you should consider using the [EventAggregator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/francischeung/archive/2008/06/02/decoupled-communication-with-prism-event-aggregation.aspx) and publishing a message to indicate a mail has loaded. This will allow you to easily have multiple loosely-coupled subscribers for this "event".

Using the EventAggregator is an elegant solution for publishing events, and leads to a much cleaner and decoupled architecture which is easier to extend. For instance, if you wish to add a new feature to email loading such as progress indication, you can simply subscribe to the `EmailLoaded` message and you're done, you don't have to tightly couple your new component to emails via an event or callback, they do not need to know about each other.